# The same string displays differently on iPad3 and iPad mini

Tags: ios, ipad, uitextview, resolution

I found a weird thing that Occasionally the same UITextView displays differently on iPad3 and iPad mini2 just like photos below. (It is OK on iPad3 but not OK on iPad mini2)

**Update:
My iPad3 is IOS6 and iPad mini2 is IOS7.
Now the problem is the same UITextView display differently by IOS version.**
Finally I solved it.
The reason is the sentence is "The\U00a0earth\U00a0revolves\U00a0around\U00a0the\U00a0sun." not "The earth revolves around the sun."
I should use half-width white space not full-width white space.

[image: iPad3]

[image: iPad mini2]

I do not know why because I think iPad3 and iPad mini2 has the same screen resolution.
Does any body can help?
thanks.

Comment: Make the string `@"The earth revolves\naround the sun"`?

Comment: check your word wrapping attribute in the main storyboard

Comment: @Kyle Yes, that's better still.

Comment: My suggestion `@"The earth revolves\naround the sun"` is a stupid one as it breaks MVC...

Comment: Do they both have the same iOS versions aswell?

Comment: @Guntis Treulands
I checked the devices and found my ipad3 is IOS6 and ipad mini2 is IOS7. I think the IOS version is the reason that causes the problem not the device. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `lineBreakMode` to `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` on the textView?

Comment: It seems UITextView does not have a property named lineBreakMode.

Comment: Try myTextView.textContainer.lineBreakMode

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Finally I solved it. The reason is the sentence is "The\U00a0earth\U00a0revolves\U00a0around\U00a0the\U00a0sun." not "The earth revolves around the sun." I should use half-width white space not full-width white space.

Answer (score 0):

The property `lineBreakMode` is not directly available in a `UITextView`and maybe not.

I recommend you to use a `UILabel` with 2 lines and here the property `lineBreakMode` is available by code or in the storyboard :

[image]

Hope that will help

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For some reason, I do need to use UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly setting this and check. But by default it is NSLineBreakByCharWrapping only.

```
  textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
```

Comment: I tried this way but still have no luck. Anyway, Thanks for your reply.